# Replacing words after specific tags into brackets using sed

Tags: xml, macos, sed

I have a xml file produced from BLAST 2.5.0+. I wish to do some changes. Specifically, I want to put all the word after OS= in my file by putting it inside []. My original file has the format like this: -

```
<Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
<Hit_id>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_id>
<Hit_def>gnl|V4U0L5| Uncharacterized protein OS=Homo sapien
OX=393305 GN=CICLE_v10008136mg PE=4 SV=1</Hit_def>
<Hit_accession>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_accession>
<Hit_len>388</Hit_len>
```

Using the following CMD : - `sed -E 's/<Hit_def>(.*)OS=([A-Za-z\.\-\,\_ ]+)(( [A-Z]+=.*))<\/Hit_def>/<Hit_def>\1[\2]\3<\/Hit_def>/g' input.xml > output.xml`, I managed to get the followings: -

```
<Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
<Hit_id>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_id>
<Hit_def>gnl|V4U0L5| Uncharacterized protein [Homo sapien]
OX=393305 GN=CICLE_v10008136mg PE=4 SV=1</Hit_def>
<Hit_accession>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_accession>
<Hit_len>388</Hit_len>
```

However, some of the words after OS= have different characteristics. For example: -

```
<Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
<Hit_id>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_id>
<Hit_def>gnl|V4U0L5| Uncharacterized protein OS=Yersinia enterocolitica serotype O:8 / biotype 1B (strain NCTC 13174 / 8081)
OX=393305 GN=CICLE_v10008136mg PE=4 SV=1</Hit_def>
<Hit_accession>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_accession>
<Hit_len>388</Hit_len>
```

Using the same CMD from above, these words will not be placed inside [] at all. What can I do to include **everything** after OS= into [] by using Mac OS X?

Comment: what is the criteria to identify the end of the string after `OS=` will it be always followed by `GN=`?

Comment: The end of the string after OS= is OX=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xslt` you can easily manipulate XML files in a more robust and powerful way than `sed`:

**INPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Hit>
        <Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
        <Hit_id>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_id>
        <Hit_def>gnl|V4U0L5| Uncharacterized protein OS=Homo sapien OX=393305 GN=CICLE_v10008136mg PE=4 SV=1</Hit_def>
        <Hit_accession>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_accession>
        <Hit_len>388</Hit_len>
</Hit>
```

**STYLESHEET:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect" extension-element-prefixes="redirect" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Hit_def">
        <xsl:variable name="stringToReplace" select="."/>
        <Hit_def><xsl:value-of select="replace($stringToReplace,'OS=([^=]*)\s+OX=','[$1] OX=')"/></Hit_def>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:hit.xml -xsl:hit.xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Hit>
   <Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
   <Hit_id>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_id>
   <Hit_def>gnl|V4U0L5| Uncharacterized protein [Homo sapien] OX=393305 GN=CICLE_v10008136mg PE=4 SV=1</Hit_def>
   <Hit_accession>TR:V4U0L5_9ROSI</Hit_accession>
   <Hit_len>388</Hit_len>
</Hit>
```

If you need the `saxon9he.jar` then get it from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/
You can also user `xsltproc` or other command available on your system.

Last but not least, you might need to trim your backreference to avoid result like `[Home Sapien     ]`. If necessary you can use the following `stylesheet`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:redirect="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/redirect" extension-element-prefixes="redirect" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" xalan:indent-amount="4"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//Hit_def">
        <xsl:variable name="stringToReplace" select="."/>
        <xsl:variable name="stringTmp" select="replace($stringToReplace,'OS=([^=]*)\s+OX=','[$1] OX=')"/>
        <Hit_def><xsl:value-of select="replace($stringTmp,'\s+\]\s+OX=','] OX=')"/></Hit_def>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much! It took a while for a beginner like me to really understand and make it worked. As a side note, for those beginners, to use it on Mac, download the saxon9he.jar and just follow the instructions from the documentation under the headline "Running XSLT from the command line". Use the command java -jar dir/saxon9he.jar -s:file.xml -xsl:stylesheet1.xsl -o:output.xml and everything will work nicely.